# Visual Studio: Toolbox C++ GUI is empty

Tags: visual-studio, c++-cli

As you can see on the image, the toolbox is empty. And I have the right UI window open. So what did I do wrong? Do I have to install more from the "workload"?

Any suggestions?

[image: Problem shown: empty toolbox Visual Studio]

Comment: You should probably add the VS version you're using.

Comment: What are you trying to make MFC? C++-CLI or something else?

Comment: Reinstall it, probably a faulty installation

Comment: @AlanBirtles Yes, C++ CLI